# How to open a $_session after curl_init()

Tags: php, session

I using `curl_init()` for xml request and response. but when pass value to session after `url_close($ch)` i getting error

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['mydata'] = "1";
session_write_close();

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_request); 
    $data_response = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 

    $xd = simplexml_load_string($data_response);
    if (($xd->DataCount) > 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['mydata'] = "0";
        session_write_close();

    }
```

But i getting error

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Node no longer exists in
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
```

Comment: remove occurrences of `session_write_close();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to close your session, you leave it open or close it at the end of your script. You can only open the session before the headers are sent out (because of cookies).

I can recommend reading the Basic Usage of sessions here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['mydata'] = "1";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_request); 
$data_response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$xd = simplexml_load_string($data_response);
if (($xd->DataCount) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['mydata'] = "0";
}
```

Comment: @NancyThomas Fixed your code, check my answer again.

Comment: ok thanks...
but i have a problem when i open another curl_init(); after $_SESSION['mydata'] = "0";

Comment: curl has no relationship with sessions.

Comment: only error when i pass value to $_SESSION['mydata'] = "0"; otherwise no error